# Provide WSUS access to Internet when using Squid proxy

Tags: windows, proxy, squid, wsus

I am planning to deploy a WSUS server. Of course this WSUS server will need access to Windows Update Catalog to download the patches. So it needs Internet access and we have a Squid proxy on the network.

I know you can configure Internet browser with the Squid Proxy URL so the users can browse the Internet but how do we give WSUS server access to the Internet to download the patches? Is there somewhere on the WSUS to allow us to specify Squid Proxy URL?

Thanks.

Comment: [The first google hit for 'wsus behind proxy'](https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/security-updates/windowsupdateservices/18127272) has the solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

[Setting up Update Synchronizations - Configuring Proxy Server Settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-server-update-services/manage/setting-up-update-synchronizations#configuring-proxy-server-settings)

> To specify a proxy server for synchronization
> In the WSUS Administration Console, click Options, and then click Update Source and Proxy Server.